# Prove that a holomorphic function is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to show that if $f:C\rightarrow C$ is holomorphic and $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f(z)=\infty$
then f is a polynomial.Let's consider $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$
Then there exists such $R$ that $$g(z) = \frac{a_{-n}}{z^n}+...+ \frac{a_{-1}}{z} + a_0 + a_1z+...$$ on disc $D(0,R) $ minus point $0$
Now we can get back to f and get that 
$$f(z)=a_{-n}z^n +...+a_{-1}z +a_0 + \frac{a_{1}}{z}+\frac{a_{2}}{z^2}+...$$
for $ |z|>R$
Now  I conclude that $|f(z)|<C|z^n|$ for some constant C and $|z|>R$ and thus from Cauchy formula I deduce that f is a polynomial.Is this a right solution?It seems pretty straightforward but I don't know how to justify the fact that
$ |\frac{a_{1}}{z}+\frac{a_{2}}{z^2}+...|<D|z^n|$$
for $ |z|>R $ and constant D.

Comment: $|\frac{a_{1}}{z}+\frac{a_{2}}{z^2}+...|$ can easily be estimated if you assume that $|z| > 1$.

Comment: no you can't say directly from $f(z)$ entire and $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$ that $g(z) = f(1/z)$ has a Laurent series with a finite number of terms on $0 < |z| < R$, that's the point you have to prove : for example with the [wiki/Casorati–Weierstrass_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Comment: and $f(z)$ entire $\implies f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converging for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ hence the Laurent series for $g(z) = f(1/z)$ is $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{1}{z^n}$ converging on every $z \ne 0$ , what you have to prove is that  only a finite number of $a_n$ are non-zero

Comment: I can prove this statement, but what should I do afterwards?Is there a nicer way to come to a conclusion then mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function's  Taylor series about $0$ is also the Laurent series in a neighbourhood of $\infty$.  But the singularity at $\infty$ is a pole, and the order of the pole determines the largest exponent that can have a nonzero coefficient in this Laurent series.

Comment: from $f(z)$ entire and $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$, I don't see how you know that the order of the pole at $\infty$ can't be $\infty$ (and hence that $g(z) = f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ and that $f(z)$ is not a polynomial), unless you use something like the [wiki/Casorati–Weierstrass_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) or Picard's great theorem.

Comment: There is no such thing as a pole of order $\infty$.  Why don't you want to use Casorati-Weierstrass to show it's not an essential singularity?

Comment: Alternatively, if $f(z)$ has limit $\infty$ at $\infty$,  $1/f(z)$ has limit $0$ there.  Thus $1/f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $\infty$, and after removing it you have a zero there.  If $1/f$ has a zero of order $p$, then $f$ has a pole of order $p$.

Comment: I know that there is no pole of order $\infty$, but this is what we are proving here. yes the removable singularity of $1/f(1/z)$ at $z=0$ looks like a good idea, thank you (you should explain it in your answer)

Comment: hence the answer is that the [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) applied to $\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$ at $z=0$ proves that $f(z)$ has to be a polynomial if it is entire and $\lim_{z\to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$

Comment: I don't really  see what's going on here.I mean what are the consequences of the fact that $\frac{1}{f(\frac{1}{z})}$ is holomorphic at and around zero?